Can i make npm install a private package and keep the VCS (.git) files?
Can i install a (private) git repository as npm dependency in a way where i can do inplace development on the package and push it back to its own repository?
At the moment i use the gitlab registry (as it is supposed to be used) and my npm module gets installed like every other node module. When i want to make changes to this package, i need to checkout the code somewhere else, make the changes there, publish the new version, update in the package.json and so on. I would really like to work on that module in the context of the project. I know i would still have to publish and update the package via npm but i could do all the work in one code-base.
What i tried so far:
{
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://oauth2:AccessToken@private-repo.tld/group/package.git"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@group/package": "^2.0.0"
    }
}

This has the same effect as simply using the private package registry. The package will be installed but the VCS information is lost.
The same goes for:
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@group/package": "git+https://oauth2:AccessToken@private-repo.tld/group/package.git#semver:^2.0.0"
    }
}

The second variant would be my preferred solution
If there is no way to do this i would really like to know what's the best approach to this "problem".
I would like to extract single pieces of the bigger project but still be able to do the development in context of the bigger project.

Maybe this could be an inspiration? I would then just replace it while developing in the package.json with the npm package.
